# Nginx reverse proxy is loading the content from two location blocks in the same request

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a nginx reverse proxy setup to route traffic to two separate projects. I want all this traffic to be on a sub domain, but depending on the route directory change the project that way.

My main site is hosted on google app engine and the secondary site is a shopify app.

So I want the app engine site to be on www.example.com and the shopify site to be on www.example.com/shop

this is my nginx config

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://appengine-app.com;
    }
    location /store {
        proxy_set_header Host example.myshopify.com;
        proxy_pass https://example.myshopify.com;
    }
}
```

When I go to `www.example.com/store` my shopify app loads and all looks good, but then after about 5 seconds my app engine app loads as well. BOTH are loading - I see the nav of my app engine app, then my whole shopify app page, then the body of my app engine app...

I don't understand how both are loading on the same window, but I feel like it has something to do with setting the proxy header for `/store` Which is the only way I could get the shopify app to load at all.

If I remove the `location /` block then the shopify app loads as I would expect - that to me shows this is a configuration issue and not an issue with my apps.

Is there some setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your `location` definitions or add an `=` so pattern matching stops (`location = /`).

You can find more information about how nginx does matching [in the documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/).

**Edit:** Just looked at google's `nginx.conf` [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-custom-runtimes-samples/blob/master/nginx/nginx.conf). Looks like the server is expecting HTTP traffic on port 8080 not the default 80.

Comment: I have tried switching the order as well as using the `location = /` with the `location = /` set, the `/store` routes work but my app engine app will only load the main page.